# How can I click at any position on-screen programmatically

Tags: android

I want to click on this position `X: 245.0 , Y: 1526.0`

I know this method [performClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()) but it is working with views only and I want to know how can click any position on the screen regardless if that was the view or not like my touch on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you talking about touching your `Activity` or anything on the screen?

for first option you can use [Activity.dispatchTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))

for second option you may use [AccessibilityService.dispatchGesture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

Comment: I want to create an auto-clicker app so I need this method to click like my touch `AccessibilityService.dispatchGesture`?

Comment: you need `AccessibilityService`, check out [THIS DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility) for more info, some code labs, patterns etc.

Comment: My App has `minSdkVersion 21` should I change it to 24 or no? because dispatchGesture added in API level 24

Comment: I don't know all possibilities of `AccessibilityService`, especially in context of new APIs. check out above linked docs and look for your desired feature. it is possible that "faking" gestures was introduced later in API 24, so you have to upgrade min sdk, as on older APIs your feature may not be possible to work

Comment: Okay, Thank You.